# How Do I Add Additional Source and Target Sheets in Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet set up to check if a cell on a source sheet in a specified column receives a value, and when it does, to copy the row to a target sheet and delete the row from the source sheet.

If the source sheet doesn't change, the code below seems to work:

```
function onEdit(event) {

    var editedCell;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Job Schedule" && r.getColumn() == 50 && r.getValue() == "X") {   //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job History");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

}
     if(r.getValue() == "H") {  //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Holding");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

} }
```

...but when I try to reverse the source and the target sheets, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function onEdit(event) {

    var editedCell;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Job Schedule" && r.getColumn() == 50 && r.getValue() == "X") {
  //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job History");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

}

  if(r.getValue() == "H") {  //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Holding");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

}

  if(s.getName() == "Job History" && r.getColumn() == 50 && r.getValue() == "R") {  //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Schedule");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

}



if(s.getName() == "Job Holding" && r.getColumn() == 50 && r.getValue() == "R") {  //the number (50=AX) must match the distance for the 'SHIPPING/SHIP' column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Schedule");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();

    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);

}
}
```

Here is what the log says:

> 2018-05-29 10:09:30.409 EDT The coordinates of the target range are
>   outside the dimensions of the sheet. at onEdit(Code:63) Expand all |
>   Collapse all {  insertId:  "qxgz0dg15to7zh"    jsonPayload: {
>   context: {    reportLocation: {…}       }   message:  "The coordinates
>   of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.
>       at onEdit(Code:63) "      serviceContext: {    service:  "AKfycbxhBfEl0hoqtNu87yC2n5H8MpwYDUhojBjI_G9okmTG"       }  }  labels:
>   {   script.googleapis.com/process_id: 
>   "EAEA1GOzXOP8tCPAT0uKRL24EjcxsGpBqJFr9-Tq8Z1rNGrlkYLWlWf7JzvIN1u0tLRPxGjJHjquTAEXXw4hn7vCf2T_UloDjcJQFHKHeKh58fJEXGg7gqfHut_j-zFd__MdCWgLRWiiOlNvTEI-f5CYhVstuN4NyZC-ulQ"
>   script.googleapis.com/project_key: 
>   "M-4Ir7ZfvYpEjdXYSVA5_ukuLxhikTIQl"
>   script.googleapis.com/user_key: 
>   "APHrgwr1ptfqh8OKASadCsz3luoVac92py5po4eQivhAsyqN3K0IxIAKMJNxdckvOON6dS9sjCXj"
>   }  logName: 
>   "projects/project-id-6367347185723609045/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"
>   receiveTimestamp:  "2018-05-29T14:09:31.411762110Z"    resource: {
>   labels: {    function_name:  "onEdit"        invocation_type:  "custom
>   function"        project_id:  "project-id-6367347185723609045"       }
>   type:  "app_script_function"     }  severity:  "ERROR"    timestamp: 
>   "2018-05-29T14:09:30.409Z"   }

Comment: Could you please provide the console logs?

Comment: @abielita How do I do that?

Comment: You may check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) on how to log information to help diagnose faults during development.

Comment: @abielita I added the log information to the original post, does that help?

Comment: Does anybody have any advice for me on this one? I still have not been able to figure it out.